# Joda-Time to java.time migration 'fromDateFields()'

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time, localdate, java.time.instant

We are currently migrating from Joda-Time to java.time. I have the following doubts about the `fromDateFields()`method. Old joda code:

```
Date date = new Date(); //some java Date
LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime.fromDateFields(date);
```

A colleague migrated it to the following lines (java.time code):

```
lt = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```

Is that correct? The [Joda-Time docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) describe the method `fromeDateFields`like this:

> Constructs a LocalDateTime from a java.util.Date using exactly the
>   same field values.
>
> Each field is queried from the Date and assigned to the LocalDateTime.
>   This is useful if you have been using the Date as a local date,
>   **ignoring the zone**.

What would be the correct way to reach the same result?

**Update** (just found the following solution):

```
lt= LocalDateTime.from(date.toInstant());
```

Comment: I would say that your colleagues code is correct, however if you want to be sure to get exact same result, implement the same method. See Joda-Time source: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.java#L232.

Comment: Looks correct. Keep in mind that the joda doc also says: "the local field values are transferred, calculated using the JDK time zone data"

Comment: Didn't think of looking at the Joda-time source code. Good hint! Also just found the following solution which looks better?  `LocalDateTime.from(date.toInstant()); ` Personally I don't like the zone part in the above code...

Answer (score 3):

I looked at Joda-Time source, and the `fromDateFields` method uses the `getXXX` methods from `java.util.Date` to get the values for the date/time fields. Something like that (I'm using Joda-Time 2.9.9):

```
return new LocalDateTime(
    date.getYear() + 1900,
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getDate(),
    date.getHours(),
    date.getMinutes(),
    date.getSeconds(),
    (((int) (date.getTime() % 1000)) + 1000) % 1000
);
```

If you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), you'll see that all these methods return the correspondent value **interpreted in the local time zone**. Which means that it's **implicity** using the JVM default timezone.

*Actually, looking at [`Date` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java), all the getters call `normalize()`, which is a method that uses the default timezone to convert the fields.*

You said that *Personally I don't like the zone part*, but in Joda-Time, it's implicity/indirectly using the default timezone.

And it makes sense to use a zone, because a [`java.util.Date` represents a point in the timeline (a specific instant)](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), without any timezone information. The same instant can correspond to a different date and time in different parts of the world, so you need a timezone to do this conversion.

Joda-Time uses the `Date::getXXX` methods, which implicity uses the default timezone. But in `java.time`, things must be more explicit, so you must use a `ZoneId` object.

By the way, your solution (`LocalDateTime.from(date.toInstant())`) didn't work for me. In Java 8, it gives an error:

> java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2018-02-01T10:50:16.882Z of type java.time.Instant

So you'll need to convert the `Date` to `Instant`, then tell in what timezone you want that, and then get the local part, just as you're already doing:

```
LocalDateTime dt = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```

Or:

```
// the result is the same
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Although `java.time` forces you to use a timezone, I believe it's a good thing, because it makes you think about it, instead of doing some "magic" behind the scenes.

And you can even change it to another timezones if needed (such as `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`). Even if you end up using the JVM's default, it was a conscient choice - ideally, because some people just use the default without thinking about it.